# How to stop reload page(HTML) in PhoneGap on navigate to previous page?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, reload, back

For going back to previous page, I did below stuff:

```
<a data-role="button" href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
```

But while came back: In `MyHtmlPage.html`,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
 },true);

$(document).ready(function(){
  });
```

these both methods are called again.

So, my question is how to stop reloading page while came back.

Comment: May be you can have some global variable flag in session storage which you can set it to true on click of back button and prevent firing events if the flag it true which can be cleared after page load

Answer (score 0):

My advice is you write onload method in MyHtmlPage.html page and control logic in that method.

Otherwise

Please use the following code,

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    //your condition
    return false;

     },true);

    $(document).ready(function(){

    //your condition
    return false;
      });
```

Comment: What about Objects that are initialised? Are they keep their respective value?